# Map TypeScript tuple recursively using variadic tuple types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a tuple of elements of different types that I would like to transform into a tuple of the same length and whose types are derived from those of the input tuple. Each element in the tuple is a class which knows how to extract a column by name of a particular type from a JSON structure. I wish to transform the extractors for which a column of the respective name is found into a subclass with an implementation for the index getter. Those which don't have a corresponding column are returned as-is.

I understand that it is not possible in Typescript to transform the elements in a tuple with `Array.map` without changing the definition globally.

I therefore wondered if it would be possible to do the operation using a recursive function which takes a variadic tuple type as an argument, but the code doesn't compile.

Is what I have in mind possible, and if so how would I go about it?

**Types**

```js
abstract class Extractor<T extends Extractor<T, S>, S> {
  constructor(public name: string) { }

  abstract withIndex(index: number): T
  abstract get index(): number
  abstract get value(): S
}

class NumberExtractor extends Extractor<NumberExtractor, number> {
  override withIndex(index: number): NumberExtractorWithIndex {
    return new NumberExtractorWithIndex(this.name, index)
  }

  override get index(): number {
    throw new Error("No index")
  }

  override get value(): number {
    throw new Error("No value")
  }
}

class NumberExtractorWithIndex extends NumberExtractor {
  constructor(name: any, private _index: number) {
    super(name)
  }

  override get index(): number {
    return this._index
  }
}

class StringExtractor extends Extractor<StringExtractor, string> {
  override withIndex(index: number): StringExtractorWithIndex {
    return new StringExtractorWithIndex(this.name, index)
  }

  override get index(): number {
    throw new Error("No index")
  }

  override get value(): string {
    throw new Error("No value")
  }
}

class StringExtractorWithIndex extends StringExtractor {
  constructor(name: any, private _index: number) {
    super(name)
  }

  override get index(): number {
    return this._index
  }
}
```

**Function using `any`s**

```js
const columns = ["A", "B", "C"]

function fnAny(...args: Extractor<any, any>[]): Extractor<any, any>[] {
  let [first, ...rest] = args

  for (const [index, column] of columns.entries()) {
    if (first.name === column) {
      first = first.withIndex(index);
      break;
    }
  }

  return args.length === 1
    ? [first]
    : [first, ...fnAny(...rest)]
}

const input = [new StringExtractor("A"), new NumberExtractor("X"), new NumberExtractor("C")] as const

console.log("input")
console.log(input)

const outputAny = fnAny(...input)

console.log("outputAny")
console.log(outputAny)
```

**Function using variadic tuple types (doesn't compile)**

```js
function fn<U extends Extractor<any, any>, V extends Extractor<any, any>[]>(...args: [U, ...V]): [U, ...V] {
  let [first, ...rest] = args

  for (const [index, column] of columns.entries()) {
    if (first.name === column) {
      first = first.withIndex(index);
    }
  }

  return args.length === 1
    ? [first]
    : [first, ...fn(...rest)]
}

const output = fn(...input)
console.log("output")
console.log(output)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgogD2nCA9lADwAqCAprhQHYAmGOe8RZANAgMoB8HPCAbwBQCJARqQoAVxZQAFAAcpIZAEtYCGsAC2FAFwJJqmgHMAlIIQBfISIShJ+BAHdVEABYBJelTnG6VAY0UtogFFBmBqR2DsyIJhSI-r6RmiFhUDHgcQgJiABuwMhSFHKpnEI2QihoGABy6eFMMLKU1PSMuC2EJA2hTV34RBzB-VDcgnYE+eFQqgEubl4+2H4rQY0RBn0ZzUNQAOpL3gHYk6KiUIlSUDSaFM4IOwNxREceJ74eqmAAdFq6DjJbBmOxVUTTWbzCi5RIIYFlDZjc4XDxQAiPGgPLBQdHyABEdQI8JW+NBonBCEhuOhsIKRRKiLSyOEFwQaIx90emFxRDkhOJhWKFDJYMqthq6Cemz2sney1ObQgtAY0rGsp6KNg4kkMh6cgB+nsNAAnhwFHNCsqEAB9YFIjIWVkXMBSBThA06Cjk6y2CEzGkLPIk05M0YZFGXa63dnuH6-O0rMVVSUYTjQYwmDVEJUqzqvEjpuambNQDhGUwTZ3UuYLVwfFZrU4O8LlDMlwZy44rSMIK4QG53LGPIuZ0vyz6rb5-Q1AlY+yk12nBhGpcPhXsczHYnl4-lEkNUUUUv1UgO1mHBoWM1IVkyb9zo7fc3kEg-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-NR4n8Yx+HEeR-EiZJ4mjvRnVMex5GWdJ018aUlSIDUu5NOIABVXMwPs1DLN4BAADUpdVGWLKcmzuBO35pu28XfL0hXbN1-XfkN1z3Jak2zqC+xDLAMKIqixBeNi1KEqSlKavSzK5my3Le0KhBit2srDQWt3at7BqQ-JlrfjaycmyobrerG30JujO5poR2gTHmqqltW9aQ82i5tst-a9M0rWzou78napYnbu2-8Xu6YY1V2KCO5B7uoBt6vqZoPGCdhhmceZpviY5sescZuRedpoQgA)

Comment: It's not clear what you wish the type of `output` would be. You're mapping the tuple using information that's only available at runtime (`typeof first.value === "string"`), so you can't possibly narrow the type of the elements in the tuple any more than `[ContainerSub, ContainerSub, ContainerSub]`

Comment: Why don't you just make a tupled array.map?

Comment: Your types are weird, they don't have `value` in their generics so they are untyped

Comment: Did you want `class Box<T>{constructor(public value: T){}}` ?

Comment: @Rubydesic I would like the type of the output tuple to be same as the input tuple. I've updated the questions to show this.

Comment: @Dimava, sorry, I chose a bad and rather confusing example. I've updated the question with a new example. I could change the definition of array.map, but I'm curious if it's possible to do it in the way I've described.

Comment: are @oal you sure that you want `class Extractor<T extends Extractor<T, S>, S>` and not just `class Extractor</* this, */ S>` ? You may have `getThis(): this {return this}` after all